# How to create iOs like looking NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nstableview, xcode4.5, nstableviewcell

**I want to create a good looking `NSTableView` with an iOs "feel" to it.** Every `NSTableView` I create looks like it's from the late-90s and feels horrible in my opinion.

*I know that there are some iOs behaviors which are probably not wanted on a Mac but it's a small and really specific table with only one column where I want to have at least some of the features from iOs...*

I started creating a `NSCustomCell` with `NSViews`, 44pixel height with different elements on it (Picture, Title, Subtitle). It kind of replicates the *look* of an `UITableView`, but I **can't replicate all the movement patterns** (Bounciness etc.) by myself. Are there any classes / libraries that help me accomplish this? Or has anybody worked on this before and can share some experiences he made?

Edit: With *"some of the features"* I mean the "momentum", the "bounciness" and something similar to the "pull to refresh" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView` has *all that features* automatically when app is launched on OS X 10.7+ (even when compiled with 10.6 SDK and target to 10.5). And considering that you use NSView as cell (that is available only on OS X 10.7+ with 10.7+ SDK) i don't see the problem, you MUST have the "momentum" and the "bounciness" automatically. Try TableViewPlayground demo and see what you are doing wrong.

p.s. 10.6 has the "momentum", but not the "bounciness".

Comment: Now I'm pretty confused. Do I have to activate all of those features programmatically? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've simply Drag&Dropped the OutlineView to my NSWindow, populated it by DataSource and it simply work... Have you tried TableViewPlayground demo?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm about to do it. I've never used an NSOutlineView before. Just NSTableViews... I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the tipp!